# Сделать скролл на данном примере без вложенного div

Tags: html, css

Можно ли реализовать этот пример без вложенного div, чтобы  был только  *div id="container"*

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>


div#container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
div#content {
    height: 1000px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 25px;
   margin:150px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 6px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/6KprJ/440/ Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вложенный див в данном случае определил высоту контента - благодаря ему скролл появляется даже с пустым блоком внутри. Если внутри будет достаточно контента - скролл появится и без вложенного блока

```
    <div id="container">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
   </div>

body {
    min-height: 1000px
}
div#container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 25px;
   margin:150px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 6px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/2zsnyg4f/